# Event timestamp and timezone

Tags: timezone, sabre

The events from ENS contains a timestamp for the event. However, I can find no indication of which timezone? It appears to be GMT-5, but will this always be the case? Does anyone know?

```
<swse:EventTimeStamp format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff">2020-09-29 03:55:14.000171</swse:EventTimeStamp>
```

Comment: I see it [in these docs](https://developer.sabre.com/event-topic-notification-messages), but you're right - there's no mention of the time zone.  In ISO8601 format (which this is) a timestamp without an offset is in *local time*, so it's likely it's the local time *relevant to the event* - but it's also possible that's not what has been implemented here.  I don't use Sabre ENS, so hard to say.  Perhaps a Sabre engineer can provide an answer below.  If you are an authorized user, you could contact their developer support directly also.

Comment: Thanks. I've reached out to Sabre. Hopefully they can tell us something. I'll relay their response here for everyone to behold.

Comment: Sabre reported back.


The time zone is always Central / GMT-5.

Furthermore the timestamp is 12-hour, so it is currently impossible to distinguish between e.g. 2020-09-29 03:53:48.000465 and 2020-09-29 15:53:48.000465 as both time stamps will be represented as 2020-09-29 03:53:48.000465.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone will vary depending on the location of your application.

I'm here in São Paulo, Brazil and my time zone is -3 GMT according to the location of SABRE's servers in Dalla, TX, USA wich is -5 GMT.

In this case my timeStamp for SABRE -2 GMT.

The important thing is that you generate your local timeStamp and Saber will always return their timeStamp in response to the services sent.